# How to use memcached in django project?

Tags: python, memcached

I am working on django-project ,I want to reduce database request overhead.
So I am trying with django-cache (Requires Memcached)

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/memcached

PORT="11211"
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="1024"
CACHESIZE="64" We increased memory size up to 256
OPTIONS="" added IP address "-l 127.0.0.1"
```

Changes settings as follows in project:Added new variable in settings.py

```
CACHE_BACKEND='memcached://localhost:11211'
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
```

[ Note : restart memcached: /etc/init.d/memcached restart]

Project is working, It reduces the database request overhead: but that brings certain issues:
I lost my session after few time. So I need to login again in application,how can I handle this,I want to store only session details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it correctly but keep in mind that if you restart memcached, you will loose all your existing sessions. That's to be expected.

Comment: Yes, I restart the memcached service after reseting settings, not for every login session, memcached losts data after restart or stop. this is not issue.